# input() discrepancy between IPython and Jupyter QtConsole

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter, nameerror

IPython:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> print input()
a
>>> 5
```

Jupyter QtConsole:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> print input()
a
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 input()
>
> C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.pyc in
>   (prompt)
>       163             self._sys_eval_input = builtin_mod.input
>
> 164 builtin_mod.raw_input = self.raw_input --> 165 builtin_mod.input =
>   lambda prompt='': eval(self.raw_input(prompt)) 166 self._save_getpass
>   = getpass.getpass 167 getpass.getpass = self.getpass C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.pyc in ()
>
> ### NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: But why is the input() function behaving differently? These are both on python 2.7.

Comment: That's strange. It looks like the Jupyter IPython kernel is replacing `input` with a function that performs the evaluation in the wrong namespace. I think this is actually a bug on their end, not yours. It might deserve a [bug report](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues).

Comment: It looks like `input()` is behaving properly in both, but it's unable to find the `a` reference in the latter case.

Comment: Could someone test this out on their end to make sure it's not due to a package I installed?

Comment: Which version of `ipython`.  I'm using Python3 with `ipython5`, have to use `eval(input())` (no need for the `print`).  No difference here.

Comment: @hpaulj: It's Python 2 specific. I'm pretty sure the bug is in the part of the traceback where it does `builtin_mod.input = lambda prompt='': eval(self.raw_input(prompt))`, replacing `input` with a function that performs the evaluation in that code's namespace instead of in `input`'s caller's namespace. You can see the code in the [repository](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/master/ipykernel/ipkernel.py#L157) for the Jupyter IPython kernel.